# In a metric space,two disjoint closed sets can be separated by two disjoint open sets.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Consider $2$ closed sets $A,B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$.Note that for $x\in A$,$d(x,B)>0$, because if for some $x\in A,d(x,B)=0$ then $x\in \overline B=B$, which contradicts the disjunction between $A$ and $B$. So, for each  $x\in A$, we can choose $\eta_x$ such that $B(x,\eta_x)\cap B=\emptyset$. Consider $E=\cup_x B(x,\eta_x)$. Similarly construct $F=\cup_yB(y,\eta_y)$. Now, it is clear that $E\cap F=\emptyset$ and $A\subset E$ and $B\subset  F$ and $E,F$ are both open. Is this correct?I just want to make sure whether my approach is correct or how can I proceed through this method.I am not looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Not quite, you need to construct $E,F$ such that they are disjoint.

Comment: It is *not* clear that $E$ and $F$ are disjoint.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What if I take $B(x,\eta_{x/2})$ and $B(y,\eta_{y/2})$

Comment: Look at @copper.hat ‘s answer for the right idea.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes he has done the same almost,we have to show a contradiction.

Comment: There is no need to reopen: the OP has been explained in comments why their approach is not correct, and provided in the answers ways to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $U = \cup_{a \in A} B(a,{1 \over 3} d_B(a))$, $V = \cup_{b \in B} B(b, {1 \over 3} d_A(b))$, note $U,V$ are open and $A \subset U, B \subset V$.

Also, for $a \in A, b \in B$ we have $d(a,b) \ge \max(d_A(b), d_B(a))$.

Suppose for contradiction that $x \in U \cap V$ then $x \in B(a,{1 \over 3} d_B(a)) \cap 
B(b, {1 \over 3} d_A(b))$ for some $a,b$ and
so 
$\max(d_A(b), d_B(a)) \le d(a,b) \le d(a,x) + d(x,b) \le {1 \over 3} (d_A(b)+d_B(a)) \le {2 \over 3} \max(d_A(b), d_B(a))$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

For any non empty set $Y \subseteq X$, the distance function $d( \cdot, Y)$ is continuous. So define $f(x) = \frac{d(x, A)}{d(x, A) + d(x, B)}$. Then $f$ is continuous, because it is a quotient of continuous functions, where the denominator never vanishes. Take $E = f^{-1}(-1/2, 1/2)$ and $F = f^{-1}(1/2, 3/2)$. They are disjoint open sets that contain $A$ and B, respectively.

Comment: Actually I know this one,I was trying to verify whether mine is correct.Anyways thanks.

Comment: Or just take $E=\{x:d(x,A)\lt d(x,B)\}$ and $F=\{x:d(x,B)\lt d(x,A)\}$.

Comment: @bof yours deserves to be a separate answer - imo the best one